# ETSI[Europe] Regulations for 2.4Ghz ISM Bandwidth Limit and RF Power

Tags: rf, communication, wireless, soc

1. I am trying to interface my STM32 with NRF24[2.4 Ghz ] or TI
   CC2500[2.4 Ghz] models. I am finding issue regarding **maximum
   allowable Bandwidth** and **RF power set** by **ETSI[Europe] EN 300 328 and EN 300 440(Short Range Devices[SRD])**
   regularity body. Kindly if someone have knowledge regarding this
   please share it. I am unable to find relevant info I have even
   consulted ETSI Official Documents but of no avail.
2. Can I even use **12Mbps** speed if I use **cc2538** SOC.
3. What is better to use a RF Transceiver (**TI CC2500**) or SOC RF Module
   (**TI CC2545** or **TI CC2538**).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying [EN300328 (Electromagnetic compatibility
and Radio spectrum Matters (ERM);
Wideband transmission systems;
Data transmission equipment operating
in the 2,4 GHz ISM band and
using wide band modulation techniques;
Harmonized EN covering the essential requirements
of article 3.2 of the R&TTE Directive)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiqoMv52rbZAhUROsAKHaWPC2IQFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.etsi.org%2Fdeliver%2Fetsi_en%2F300300_300399%2F300328%2F01.09.01_60%2Fen_300328v010901p.pdf&usg=AOvVaw20pkpQ9WfLv_Bq6UdOGfIy) is the document you need because your question is lacking in detail but this is a good example of 2.4 GHz transmission power and bandwidth requirements: -

[image]

Regards your other questions, you will have to read the data sheet for the devices yourself to ascertain what maximum data rates they can run at and, "which one is better?" - what does "better" mean in this context: -

- Smaller?
- Nicer?
- Cheaper?
- Easier to set-up?
- More power efficient?

The list could go on!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this detail. I'm looking at their datasheet to compare them. The document you have share is about wideband transmisson system i am looking for Short Range Device(SRD). Can you tell me about the document from which you share this table ?  Is the document you share have this table document ? can you tell the page number ?

Comment: I found both document and picture independently. I'll see if there is a link to the picture.....

Comment: [Here](https://interferencetechnology.com/new-eu-requirements-test-methods-2-4-ghz-ism-data-transmission-equipment/) is a link to where the table was found.

Comment: Did you find what you are looking for?

Comment: @HassaanShah BTW it is normally good practice when editing a question so that you can embed new information provided in an answer, that you make it clear that the "new" information came about as a result of an answer given. Not doing that dilutes my answer's contribution and can lead to some people down-voting my answer.